# AngularJs - Some jQuery plugins are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am newer to AngularJs. i am trying to use some jQuery plugins with AngularJs.

But some jQuery plugins was not working with AngularJs dynamic constants but after calling it in the controller it is working now. like.. `CKEDITOR`

and some of them are still not working  like `mCustomScrollbar`  even i call it in the controller

```
app.controller('collectionPoints',  ['$scope',function($scope)  {

        CKEDITOR.replace('ck_editor');   // Working
        $("#selector").mCustomScrollbar();  // Working with contacts that load it the first time but not working with dynamic contents        
   }
);
```

Comment: https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor

Comment: ckeditor is working but `mCustomScrollbar` is not working.

Comment: Oh, I don't know this plugin, but Google: `<plugin name> angularjs directive` and i'm sure something will come up

Comment: What about https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor ?